# Script to modify text inputfile and run in a loop

Tags: python, bash, perl

I do have an input file in the next format:

> 2 **15** 1 5 1
>
> ORTG.data  46.7  28.1 33 120
>
> HDC3.data 169.7  89.4 47 120
>
> ../../GFS/costa_47d**15** 0 120
>
> ../../GFS/costa_171d**15** 0 120
>
> mtinvout

Where the number 15 corresponds to depth. I'd to get your help to create an script in bash or python that allows to do a loop search by depth. I mean, to substitute the 15 by 16, 17, 18, etc.

I do have a simple perl line:

> perl -pi -e 's/14/15/g' mt_inv.in

But it doesn't run as a loop.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
oldString=15
newString=16
file="/path/to/file"

while [ newString -lt 50 ]; do
  sed "s/${oldString}/${newString}/g" "$file";
  echo "$file"
  let newString=newString+1
done
```

Or if you want it to actually create new files with the replaced number

```
#!/bin/bash
oldString=15
newString=16
file="/path/to/file"

while [ newString -lt 50 ]; do
  sed "s/${oldString}/${newString}/g" "$file" > "$file.$newString";
  let newString=newString+1
done
```